# are HashMaps with predefined capacity faster

Tags: java, hashmap

I came across an algorithm on the net http://www.coderanch.com/t/201836/Performance/java/Hashtable-vs-Hashmap
 and decided to test it

```
public class MapTest{
    static int sizeOfTrial = 100000;
    static String[] keys = new String[sizeOfTrial];
    static String[] vals = new String[sizeOfTrial];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //init sizeOfTrial key/value pairs
        for (int i=0; i < sizeOfTrial; i++){
          String s1 = "key"+ i;
          String s2 = "val"+ i;
          keys[i] = s1;
          vals[i] = s2;
        }
        test(new TreeMap(), "TreeMap");
        test(new Hashtable(), "Hashtable");
        test(new HashMap(), "HashMap");
        test(new Hashtable(200000), "Hashtable presized");
        test(new HashMap(200000), "HashMap presized");
    }

  public static void test(Map tm, String name){
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0; i < sizeOfTrial; i++){
      tm.put(keys[i],vals[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i < sizeOfTrial; i++){
      tm.get(keys[i]);
    }
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("total time for " + name + ": " + (t2-t1));
  }
}
```

and i got the following results

```
total time for TreeMap: 1744
total time for Hashtable: 446
total time for HashMap: 234
total time for Hashtable presized: 209
total time for HashMap presized: 196
```

Is this JVM dependent and arbitrary or does it really provide faster access and storage time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Predefining the expected size of any container-type class will provide faster storage time simply because the storage doesn't have to be dynamically re-allocated at runtime as often.  Usually the backing storage is some sort of array, and when you go beyond the available capacity, the array has to be copied into a new larger array.  This is an expensive operation that may have to happen multiple times if you store a large number of objects into a container that started at a very small capacity.

The performance of reading from the map shouldn't be affected either way.  You could demonstrate this better by timing the `tm.put` part separately from the `tm.get` part.

---

**Edit**: To illustrate this point further, I modified the code to time `tm.put` separately from `tm.get`.  Here are the results on my machine:

```
total time for TreeMap tm.put: 159
total time for TreeMap tm.get: 74
total time for Hashtable tm.put: 20
total time for Hashtable tm.get: 10
total time for HashMap tm.put: 42
total time for HashMap tm.get: 5
total time for Hashtable presized tm.put: 11
total time for Hashtable presized tm.get: 9
total time for HashMap presized tm.put: 6
total time for HashMap presized tm.get: 4
```

Notice that the difference between `Hashtable` regular and presized for `tm.put` is a factor of ~2.  SImilarly, with `HashMap` the difference between regular and presized is a factor of ~7 for storing.  However, looking at the reading side, both `Hashtable` and `Hashmap` have roughly the same timings for `tm.get` in both cases (`10 ms` vs `9 ms` for `Hashtable`, and `5 ms` vs `4 ms` for `HashMap`).  Also notice that in the presized case, both putting and getting take roughly about the same amount of total time.

Comment: This only holds true if the predefined size isn't exceeded. If it is then the predefined one will do a copy as well.

Comment: @twain249: True.  Clarified with the words "as often".

Comment: how about not only retrieval but also storing new values against an old key..will it be faster under that circumstance ??

Comment: @Nav: No. Predefined capacity is only relevant for adding brand new keys because that expands the total size of the backing storage and leads to the potential resize operation.